# Angular state complex URL hierarchy mapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular StateProvider for an Ionic App. Following are the states:

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/sign-in');
$stateProvider.state('start', {
url: '/sign-in',
templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
controller:  'loginController'
})
 $stateProvider.state('pageshow', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'templates/page_titles.html',
  controller:  'pageController',
  params:{subStructure:null}
})
$stateProvider.state('titledetail', {
  url: '/page-details/:param1',
  templateUrl: 'templates/title_detail.html',
  controller:  'pageDetailsController',
  params: {item: null}
})
```

I have JSON which I'm supposed to map with the above states. The JSON looks something like [this](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d5de28ef7244ca366a1db95ac0d27224). There can be only two states, `pageshow` and `titledetail`. How can I set-up the URLs for states such that the folder type objects map to `pageshow` and page type objects map to `titledetail`
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What data needs to be shown on a particular URL hit should be determined by Controller associated with the state. Or you can use the same controller and pass the query string in URL to determine what data needs to be shown. In your case 'param1' in 'titledetail' state

Comment: @CoderJohn I understand that part perfectly. I think I couldn't explain myself. This is a very deep structure(N-deep) and all I want is for all the URL schemes like dashboard/`{folderid}`/`{folderid}`/`{folderid}` and the like to map to the `pageshow` state and all the dashboard/`{folderid}`/`{folderid}`/`{pageid}` to map to the `titledetail` state